# Flutter - Checking if a data has changed in Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, mobile

I am developing a mobile application with Flutter and I am using Firebase Firestore as database.

I want to listen to the `Help` field in the `users` collection in Firestore, in the documents I obtained with the for loop. I want to send a notification if and if there has been a change and this change is true and that change is `true`.

I wrote the following code for this:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:treedisaster/services/notification.dart';

Future<void> listenToFirestoreChanges() async {
  var getCurrentUserData = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("users")
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
      .get();
  var getPersons = getCurrentUserData.data()!["Persons"] as List;

  for (String user in getPersons) {
    final docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user);
    var initialHelpValue =
        await docRef.get().then((snapshot) => snapshot.data()?['Help']);

    docRef.snapshots().listen(
      (DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) async {
        if (snapshot.exists && snapshot.data() != null) {
          var currentHelpValue = snapshot.data()!['Help'];
          if (initialHelpValue != currentHelpValue) {
            print('$user Change detected');
            await NotificationService()
                .showNotification(title: "test", body: "test");
            initialHelpValue = currentHelpValue;
          }
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

But unfortunately code it does not work. Can you help me? Thanks in advance to all of you.

Comment: Did you already step through the code in a debugger to see what happens in your `listen` callback? So: set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line. When you do this, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ·Hello. I looked at the values ​​of `initialHelpValue` and `currentHelpValue` . Both happen the same. Both are `false` if `false` in the database. If `true`, both are `true`.

Comment: That seems expected when you first run the code. Only when you then change the value in the database would your `initialHelpValue` and `currentHelpValue` have different values. Is that not what you expected?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen · Yes.

Comment: We cannot able to track the certain field in the document, we have to listen for the entire document as we will listen for the snapshot change so the updated code should look something like this [snippet](https://codefile.io/f/DJ8yEMhLuE). Also we are using await at singular level not on the entire document to save reads.

Answer (score 0):

You can find here [Firestore doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#dart) various examples of document listening